# How to implement Nullable properties in Realm objects (DateTime more exactly)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-net

The question is really simple, about how to workaround this error:

> Fody/RealmWeaver: class 'X' field 'Y' is a
>   'System.Nullable`1' which is not yet supported.

This is for a `DateTime?` property. [Nullable primitive types are indeed supported](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#optional-properties).

I know the Java version supports `null` values. This is about Realm .NET. I was wondering if there's any other way besides doing the old `DateTime SomeNullableProperty` & `bool HasSomeNullableProperty` thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We implement the standard optional properaties such as `int?` and `bool?` for primitives. This is briefly mentioned in our docs under [optional properties](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#optional-properties)

Reference types such as `String` can be null.

We also support the optional value type `DateTimeOffset?`.

See the full list in the [AccessTests.cs](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/Tests/Tests.Shared/AccessTests.cs)

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I was actually trying with a `DateTime?` (value type) and got that error. Is this supported as well?

Comment: No, if you had tried just a straight DateTime you would have got the error saying we only support DateTimeOffset. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2012/04/06/datetime-and-datetimeoffset-in-net-good-practices-and-common-pitfalls/ is a good explanation why.

Comment: Yes, no `DateTime?` support yet. I'll create an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe it's worth switching.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to add a boolean field for every field
you want to allow nullability.